# Can you square both sides of an equation containing matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

For example A=λI ⇒ A²=λ²I where A is square, and λ∈ℝ.
Or more generally AB=CD ⇒ ABAB=CDCD.
Assuming all the necessary matrix products are possible, what other conditions would need to be fulfilled for this to hold?

Comment: None!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Assume all are square.  If not, I'll m\leave comment to others.

Comment: The two equations you have written are both true for all matrices. You only need to be careful when you swap the order of multiplication. For instance, $(AB)^2$ is _not_ necessarily $A^2B^2$

Comment: The general principle is that whenever a function $f$ is well-defined on a set $S$, if $a = b \in S$ then $f(a) = f(b)$.

Comment: Of course you can do this. This has nothing to do with matrices. It's just logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my money, the answer you’re looking for has nothing whatever to do with matrices. For, in mathematics, when we write$$A=B$$ we’re saying that $A$ and $B$ are *the same thing*. In your case, you’re not talking about one matrix $AB$ and another matrix $CD$, rather you’re talking about *a single matrix* that has two factorizations.

Thus the principle that “you may always do something to one side of an equation as long as you do the same thing to the other” is not a mathematical principle, but rather a principle of logic, dependent on the mathematical meaning of equality.

Answer (score 1):

$AB=CD$

$\Rightarrow ABAB=CDAB$

$\Rightarrow ABAB=CDCD$

In words: you are allowed to right multiply both sides by $AB$, which is the same as $CD$, so the answer is yes (given that you can actually square the matrix, i.e. that it is a square matrix).